# Универсальный метод для подстановки значений с БД для отрисовки кольцевых диаграмм?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
 // Компонент с разметкой (версткой, данными с БД и функционалом)

    <template>
        <div class="medicine-medical">
            <div class="medicine-medical_transform transform">
                <div class="notransform">
                    <span>Медосмотр</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="medicine-medical_block">
                <chart :parameterValue="+worker.parameters[468]" :inputDataType="'medicalCheckup'"/>
                <div class="img" ref="imgMedical"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="medicine-breathalyzer">
            <div class="medicine-breathalyzer_transform transform">
                <div class="notransform">
                    <span>Прохождение <br> алкотестера</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="medicine-breathalyzer_block">
                <chart :breathalyzer="+worker.parameters[474]" :inputDataType="'breathalyzer'"/>
                <div class="img"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="medicine-individual_block">
                <chart :userMedicalReplacement="worker.worker_siz"/>                                              <!-- вызов диаграммы -->
                <div class="exclamation" v-if="frameStyleBlock.danger"></div>                                           <!-- скрываем восклицательный знак -->
                <div class="img"></div>
                <div class="medicine-individual_block-block" :style="frameStyleBlock.block">                            <!-- устанавливаем стили для блока с таблицей -->

                    <div class="medicine-individual_block-block__header"
                         @dblclick="addModalSIZ()"
                         onmousedown="return false" onselectstart="return false"
                         :style="frameStyleBlock.header">                                                               <!-- стили и событие клика для шапка таблицы -->

                        <div class="triangle"></div>
                        <span>необходимо заменить</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="medicine-individual_block-block__line"
                         v-for="(key, index) in sortReplacement">                                                       <!-- цикл для сортировки и окрашивания в зависимости от значений сроков СИЗ -->
                        <span>{{index + 1}} . {{ key.siz_title }}</span>
                        <span :style="setColorAfter(key.date_to_replacement_siz)" > {{ setText(key.date_to_replacement_siz) }}</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
    </template>

// Компонент с диаграммами 
<template>
    <div class="chart__window">

        <svg width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 42 42">
            <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="6"></circle>
            <circle v-bind="diagramStyle"></circle>
        </svg>

        <span class="v">{{ returnFormattedValue(inputDataType, parameterValue) }}</span>                  

    </div>
</template>
```

export default {
        name: "employeeCardChart",                                                                                      // Имя компонента

```
    components: {                                                                                                   // Локальная регистрация компонента
        'chart': Chart
    },

    props: ['inputDataType', 'parameterValue'],                                                                     // Свойства, передаваемые от родительского компонента(определяем тип и значение)

    data: function () {                                                                                             // Исходные данные
        return {
            warning: false,
            danger: false,
            success: false,
            textColor: ''
        }
    },

    methods: {
        returnFormattedValue(inputDataType, parameterValue) {
            if (inputDataType === 'breathalyzer' || inputDataType === 'examiner') {
                return parameterValue + ' %';
            } else {
                return parameterValue + ' ДН';
            }
        }
    },

    computed: {                                                                                                     // Вычисляемые свойства

        diagramStyle() {                                                                                            // Стили для диаграммы

            const inputDataType = this.inputDataType;
            const length = 100;                                                                                     // Примем длину окружности за константу
            const radius = length / (Math.PI * 2);                                                                  // Примем радиус окружности за константу
            const dash = inputDataType;                                                                             // Штрих - заполненная часть окружности.
            const space = length - dash;                                                                            // Промежуток - соответственно, не заполненная.
            let stroke = 'rgb(181, 90, 110, 1)';                                                                    // Цвет линии по умолчанию.

            switch (inputDataType) {
                case 'breathalyzer':
                    console.log(`зашел в кейс breathalyzer`);
                    if(this.parameterValue >= 99) {
                        console.log(`больше 99 дней`);
                        stroke = 'rgb(178, 214, 60, 1)';
                    } else {
                        console.log(`меньше 98 дней`);
                        stroke = 'rgb(181, 90, 110, 1)';
                    }
                    break;
                case 'examiner':
                    console.log(`зашел в кейс examiner`);
                    if(this.parameterValue >= 90) {
                        console.log(`больше 90 дней`);
                        stroke = 'rgb(178, 214, 60, 1)';
                    } else if (this.parameterValue >= 51 && this.parameterValue <= 90) {
                        console.log(`от 52 до 89 дней`);
                        stroke = 'rgb(239, 127, 26, 1)';
                    } else {
                        console.log(`меньше 51 дня`);
                        stroke = 'rgb(181, 90, 110, 1)';
                    }
                    break;
                case 'medicalCheckup':
                    console.log(`зашел в кейс medicalCheckup`);
                    if(this.parameterValue >= 30) {
                        console.log(`больше 30 дней`);
                        stroke = 'rgb(178, 214, 60, 1)';
                    } else if (this.parameterValue >= 7 && this.parameterValue <= 29) {
                        console.log(`больше 6дней меньше 30 дней`);
                        stroke = 'rgb(239, 127, 26, 1)';
                    } else {
                        console.log(`меньше 7 дней`);
                        stroke = 'rgb(181, 90, 110, 1)';
                    }
                    break;
                case 'certification':
                    if(this.parameterValue >= 0) {
                        stroke = 'rgb(178, 214, 60, 1)';
                    }
                    break;
                case 'userMedicalReplacement':
                    if (this.parameterValue && Array.isArray(this.parameterValue)) {
                        for (let i = 0; i < this.parameterValue.length; i++) {
                            if (this.parameterValue[i].date_to_replacement_siz <= 3 && this.parameterValue[i].date_to_replacement_siz >= 1) {
                                this.warning = true;
                                stroke = 'rgb(239, 127, 26, 1)';
                            }
                            if (this.parameterValue[i].date_to_replacement_siz < 1) {
                                this.danger = true;
                                stroke = 'rgb(181, 90, 110, 1)';
                            }
                            if (this.parameterValue[i].date_to_replacement_siz >= 4) {
                                this.success = true;
                                stroke = 'rgb(178, 214, 60, 1)';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return {
                'cx': 21, // координата центра окружности по оси абцисс
                'cy': 21, // координата центра окружности по оси ординат
                'r': radius, // радиус окружности или просто: 15.91549431
                'fill': 'none', // заливка элемента
                'stroke': stroke, // цвет линии
                'stroke-width': 4, // толщина линии
                'stroke-dasharray': `${dash} ${space}`, // штрих и промежуток
                'stroke-dashoffset': 25 // смещение пунктирной обводки
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Суть вопроса... Есть два метода, устанавливает в конце значения либо процент либо день, а другой на вход принимает данные с базы(но это не точно))). Но приходит одно значение medicalCheckup и диаграмма закрашена полностью, хотя пришло значение = 21... что я мог упустить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отформатируйте код. Читать его не приятно..Программирование — точная наука.

Comment: `(this.parameterValue && Array.isArray(this.parameterValue)` не совсем понятны вычисления в этом участке кода.

Comment: Проверка(если значение пришло и это массив...то...)

Comment: Это понятно, что проверка и массив ) Но как массив значений может влиять на цвет?

Comment: Это же каждая последующая итерация будет затирать значение, полученное в результате вычислений для текущей итерации.

Comment: @doox911 может есть какая-то другая реализация кода?

Comment: суть в том что приходящие значения окрашиваются и формируются в таблицу в которой происходит сортировка...

Comment: Формирование таблицы в компоненте круговой диаграммы - это несколько перебор.

Comment: табличка не большая с выпадашкой из нескольких строк...скрин приложил

Comment: Вопрос желательнее заранее подготавливать, а не по частям выкладывать. Либо разбить на несколько, чтобы вопросы относились к конкретным проблемам, которые у вас возникли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> что я мог упустить?

Чтобы ничего не упускать, проблему необходимо локализовать, а также выполнять валидацию входных [параметров](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2). Если "потрясти" ваш `// Компонент с разметкой` и оставить только необходимые данные для вопроса:

```html
<chart :parameterValue="+worker.parameters[468]" :inputDataType="'medicalCheckup'" />
<chart :breathalyzer="+worker.parameters[474]" :inputDataType="'breathalyzer'" />
<chart :userMedicalReplacement="worker.worker_siz" />
```

А теперь обратите внимание на участок в компоненте круговой диаграммы:

```
props: ['inputDataType', 'parameterValue'],
```

---

Чтобы придать универсальности вашему компоненту круговой диаграммы, нужно добавить параметр максимального значения. Это позволит отображать значения не только в процентах, но и в физических величинах (кг, дни, калории и т. д.):

```
// Штрих - заполненная часть окружности.
// Переводим в процентное соотношение.
let dash = this.$props.parameterValue / this.$props.max * 100;

// Промежуток - не заполненная часть окружности.
let space = 100 - dash;
```

В таком случае атрибут: *stroke-dasharray* будет `${dash} ${space}`.

---

Итого, с учетом вышеизложенного:

```
props: {
  inputDataType: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  parameterValue: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  max: {
    type: Number,
    default: 100
  }
}
```

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

// Компонент круговой диаграммы.
const Chart = {
  // Имя компонента.
  name: 'chart',
  // Свойства, передаваемые от родительского компонента.
  props: {
    inputDataType: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    parameterValue: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    // Максимальное допустимое значение
    // для свойства `parameterValue`.
    max: {
      type: Number,
      default: 100
    }
  },
  // Вычисляемые свойства.
  computed: {
    // Стили для диаграммы.
    diagramStyle() {
      // Определим локально для удобства.
      const val = this.parameterValue;

      // Цвет линии по умолчанию.
      let stroke = 'rgb(181, 90, 110, 1)';

      switch (this.inputDataType) {
        case 'breathalyzer':
          stroke = val >= 99 ? 'rgb(178, 214, 60, 1)' : stroke;
          break;
        case 'examiner':
          stroke = val >= 90 ? 'rgb(178, 214, 60, 1)' :
            val >= 51 ? 'rgb(181, 90, 110, 1)' : stroke;
          break;
        case 'medicalCheckup':
          stroke = val >= 30 ? 'rgb(178, 214, 60, 1)' :
            val >= 7 ? 'rgb(239, 127, 26, 1)' : stroke;
          break;
        case 'certification':
          stroke = val >= 0 ? 'rgb(178, 214, 60, 1)' : stroke;
          break;
        case 'userMedicalReplacement':
          stroke = val >= 4 ? 'rgb(178, 214, 60, 1)' :
            val <= 3 && val >= 1 ? 'rgb(239, 127, 26, 1)' : stroke;
          break;
      }

      // Штрих - заполненная часть окружности.
      // Переводим в процентное соотношение.
      let dash = val / this.$props.max * 100;

      // Промежуток - не заполненная часть окружности.
      let space = 100 - dash;

      return {
        // цвет линии
        'stroke': stroke,
        // штрих и промежуток
        'stroke-dasharray': `${dash} ${space}`,
        // смещение начала пунктирной обводки
        'stroke-dashoffset': 25
      }
    },
    // В данном случае лучше использовать вычисляемое свойство.
    formattedValue() {
      if (['breathalyzer', 'examiner'].includes(this.$props.inputDataType)) {
        return this.$props.parameterValue + ' %';
      }

      return this.$props.parameterValue + ' ДН.';
    }
  },
  // Шаблон компонента.
  template: `<div class="chart__window">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42">
        <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549431" fill="transparent" stroke-width="6" stroke="#d2d3d4" class="donut-ring"></circle>
        <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549431" fill="transparent" stroke-width="4" v-bind="diagramStyle"></circle>
      </svg>
    <span class="v">{{inputDataType}}<br>{{ formattedValue }}</span>
  </div>`,
}

// Создаем экземпляр приложения.
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // Локальная регистрация компонентов.
  components: {
    'chart': Chart
  },
  // Исходные данные. Модели.
  data: {
    worker: {
      worker_size: 2,
      parameters: {
        474: 15,
        468: 12
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.chart__window {
  width: 288px;
  height: 288px;
  position: relative;
}

.v {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: cursive;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="range" v-model.number="worker.parameters[474]" min="0" max="100" />
  <input type="range" v-model.number="worker.parameters[468]" min="0" max="45" />
  <input type="range" v-model.number="worker.worker_size" min="0" max="7" step=".5" />
  <div class="container">
    <chart :parameter-value="worker.parameters[474]" :input-data-type="'breathalyzer'"></chart>
    <chart :parameter-value="worker.parameters[468]" :input-data-type="'medicalCheckup'" :max="45"></chart>
    <chart :parameter-value="worker.worker_size" :input-data-type="'userMedicalReplacement'" :max="7"></chart>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```